# Pattern match using regex

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I'm reading a textfile and trying to match a pattern to a line line of textfile.

For example, if in my text file a line looks like `IT&&HOD&&name'S.Roy'`, then in my program I'm trying to store similar pattern in the `String z` variable and then match `z` with text file pattern to get the output as `S.Roy`.

When I store in different string like `String b="IT&&HOD&&name.*"` and use regex to match b with the textfile line, then it results right ie. `S.Roy`.

However,  when the `String z` (which has same value stored as `b`) is matched with textfile line then it shows `"no match found"`.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String txt=request.getParameter("query");
    if (txt.matches("Who is the(.*)")) {
        String re1=".*?";   
        String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re3=".*?";
        String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re5=".*?";   
        String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re7=".*?";   
        String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; 
        String re9=".*?";   
        String re10="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  
        String re11=".*?";  
        String re12="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find())
        {
            String word1=m.group(1);
            String word2=m.group(2);
            String z=word2.toString()+"&&"+word1.toString()+"&&"+"name.*"+"\n";

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/database.txt"));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if( Pattern.matches(z,strLine)){
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
                    if (matcher.find()){
                        String a = matcher.group(1);
                        request.setAttribute("a",a);
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);     
                    }
                }
            }       
       }
       else{
           String a="Match not found";
           request.setAttribute("a",a);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);  
       }
  }     
  else{
      String a = "Sorry......Invalid query !!!";
      request.setAttribute("a",a);
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response); 
   }     
}
```

For any query `"Who is the HOD of IT"` `String z` results in `IT&&HOD&&name.*`
and in my `database.txt` it is stored as `IT&&HOD&&name'S.Roy'` so trying to match these two it should result in `S.Roy` but it is not doing so. Please help.

Comment: What is the end result of finding match?  Are you just trying to parse/separate the line?

Comment: I am trying to read the textfile to find a pattern same as value of string z and then for that string in the textfile to print whatever within ' '. For eg in my textfile i stored IT&&HOD&&name'S.Roy' now my z results pattern IT&&HOD&&name.* and matching these patterns i want the end result as S.Roy but it results match not found. But when i stored same value of z in another string like String b=" IT&&HOD&&name.* " and now tried to match b and textfile pattern then it gives desired result

Comment: My question is this whatever the value of String b same result comes from string z also then why pattern match with b gives the result and pattern match with z  gives 'match not found'. please help !!!

Comment: Can you post a few more examples of the data strings?  Is it ALWAYS `"IT&&HOD&&name..."`?  Also, please post the exact data you want to extract?  Are you trying to pull out IT, then HOD, then the name?  Your code is not very clear.

Comment: Say for any query Who is PM of the country then eg. in database it will be stored as ie strline will be  country&&PM&&name'N.Modi' and String z result would be country&&PM&&name.* and Pattern match (z,strline) should result N.Modi

Comment: You are well within your rights to roll back my edit, but your chances of getting a useful answer would be greatly improved if you provided an alternative edit of your own to make your English comprehensible and to format your code legibly.

Comment: Sorry I am new in stackoverflow i wanted to apply it instead it got rolled back. How should i approve it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your code, but here's what you should be doing to get three parts from your pattern which is in the format:

> [category]&&[title]&&name'[name]'

For just finding if the line is in the right format (and only a-z upper/lower is used along with . and [space] for name), then this regex would do the trick:

```
^[A-Za-z]+&{2}[A-Za-z]&{2}name'[ .A-Za-z]+'$
```

For extraction there is no need for regex, especially for getting the first two parts since you have a delimiter of `"&&"`.  The second part you can use regex, but a simple replace might be even easier to use.  Regex isn't really needed at all for this, assuming that you want to actually extract the data.

This is how I would extract those values from the line & validate:

```
String category;
String title;
String name;
String line = /* populated from where ever */
//validate line is in correct format
if(str.matches("^[A-Za-z]+&{2}[A-Za-z]&{2}name'[A-Za-z]+'$")){
    String[] parts = str.split("&&");
    category = parts[0];
    title = parts[1];
    String temp = str.replace("name'","");
    name = temp.replace('\'',"");
}
```

Your question isn't very clear, but I hope this at least points you in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Please help me with one thing -----  If word2=IT and word1=HOD then is                                                                                                         String z=word2.toString()+"&&"+word1.toString()+"&&"+"name.*"+"\n"; and     String y=" IT&&HOD&&name.* " are same. ie. is string y and z are of same value?

Comment: @SoumyasreeBiswas Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm asking whether however I have written my z string will it result same as my y string

Comment: You need to use better variables names that actually describe their purpose. Your code is full of smells like this.  What does `String z` represent?  There is no `y` in your code, nor in my example.

Comment: Thank you to all actually i could not explain my problem thank you for bearing with me actually it was only a newline creating the problem now i got it fixed and i created such a mess asking stupid questions. So thank you.